# C# recognize computer when starting the application

Tags: c#

Can you tell me how to recognize the computer where the desktop application is installed using C# when starting the application?

Comment: What do you want? IP? MachineName? MAC address? What if it is virtual machine? Please, specify concrete data you want to check for recognition.

Comment: Are looking to achieve some kind of licensing?

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for the machine name???

```
Environment.MachineName
```

Comment: Probably, OP asked for recognition. It means he have some fingerprints to identify.